# Grassmanian is a coherent space

Tags: general-topology, grassmannian

How to prove that  Grassmanian is a coherent space? 
I was thinking about it and I can't understand how to build a path from one subspace to another, if each subspace is determined by the matrix and rank of this matrix is the same of degree of subspace?

Comment: What do you mean by *coherent*? From your question, I'd guess what you actually mean to ask is how to prove that it is path-connected.

Comment: @Stephen Exactly, I wanted to say that Crassmanian is a connected space

Comment: There are many ways to do this. One way is to show that the general linear group acts transitively, then show that the general linear group is connected, which is a bit easier.